# How to activate an action with a button using python?

Tags: python, rigging

I'm making an Iron Man helmet.  I have rigged it and animated it.
I want to make a custom UI panel to control the animated action.  I'm completely new to scripting and I have no idea how to do it. Basically I want the action to be activated when the button in the panel is pressed.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Depending on what your using it for, it would be easier to do it in the game engine.

Answer (score 2):

With this code you can trigger an action (adding a plane into Scene) with a Button in 'UI Panel' using Python.

```
import bpy
from random import randint

class UIPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "This is UI panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.operator("object.plane", text='click to add', icon="BLENDER")

class OBJECT_OT_AddButton(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.plane"
    bl_label = "Add a plane to the scene"

    def execute(self, context):
        print ("This is a test print statement")
        x = randint(0,10)
        y = randint(0,10)
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(location=(x,y,0))
        return {'FINISHED'}

bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
```